# How can I add another row to the total field in WooCoommerce cart, checkout and recipe mail?

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic

I've searched a lot to find out how I can add a custom row inside the total costs in my WooCommerce shop and checked out the hooks but can't find the solution. This is what I've tried:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_order_item_totals', 'bbloomer_add_recurring_row_email', 10, 2 );

function bbloomer_add_recurring_row_email( $total_rows, $myorder_obj ) {

$total_rows['recurr_not'] = array(
    'label' => __( 'Rec:', 'woocommerce' ),
    'value' => 'blabla'
);

return $total_rows;
}
```

But this only adds the row to the total rows in the recipe email. I need to change my total row, add a new row with a name and a value calculated from the cart subtotal field.

This is how I need it:

[image]

Do you now how to to this? I have no plan. Thanks for your help!

Comment: do you want to add extra price in that custom row?

Comment: Yes, I want to add a row with a custom label and a custom price calculated from the cart subtotal value above for example value = (getSubtotal() * 100);

Comment: Exactly below the Subtotal is not possible. try to edit this file 'cart-totals.php'

Comment: @PullataPraveen but this would be a problem because of plugin updates etc.

Comment: @jojnny97 you can add woocommerce  folder and that page inside the woocommerce in your child theme and then you can edit

Comment: @PullataPraveen If your theme has a woocommerce.php file, you will be unable to override the woocommerce/archive-product.php custom template in your theme, as woocommerce.php has priority over other template files. This is intended to prevent display issues.

And I have this file in the Divi theme

Answer (score 1):

Its too late but it can still help to others who are looking for the same :

Copy "plugins\woocommerce\templates\cart\cart-totals.php" to 
"your-theme\woocommerce\templates\cart\cart-totals.php"

Open "your-theme\woocommerce\templates\cart\cart-totals.php" and add the following line inside the table tag

```
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_cart_totals_custom_text' ); ?>
```

Then open your function.php and add the following:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_totals_custom_text', 'action_woocommerce_cart_totals_before_shipping', 10, 0 ); 

function action_woocommerce_cart_totals_before_shipping(  ) {
     echo "<tr class='cart-subtotal'><th>Title</th><td>Text</td></tr>";
}
```

Here is the result

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Try This:

```
        // Add a custom field before single add to cart
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'custom_product_price_field', 5 );
function custom_product_price_field(){
    echo '<div class="custom-text text">
    <p>Extra Charge ('.get_woocommerce_currency_symbol().'):</p>
    <input type="text" name="custom_price" value="" placeholder="e.g. 10" title="Custom Text" class="custom_price text_custom text">
    </div>';
}

// Get custom field value, calculate new item price, save it as custom cart item data
add_filter('woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'add_custom_field_data', 20, 2 );
function add_custom_field_data( $cart_item_data, $product_id ){
    if (! isset($_POST['custom_price']))
        return $cart_item_data;

    $custom_price = (float) sanitize_text_field( $_POST['custom_price'] );
    if( empty($custom_price) )
        return $cart_item_data;

    $product    = wc_get_product($product_id); // The WC_Product Object
    $base_price = (float) $product->get_regular_price(); // Product reg price

    // New price calculation
    $new_price = $base_price + $custom_price;

    // Set the custom amount in cart object
    $cart_item_data['custom_data']['extra_charge'] = (float) $custom_price;
    $cart_item_data['custom_data']['new_price'] = (float) $new_price;
    $cart_item_data['custom_data']['unique_key'] = md5( microtime() . rand() ); // Make each item unique

    return $cart_item_data;
}

// Set the new calculated cart item price
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'extra_price_add_custom_price', 20, 1 );
function extra_price_add_custom_price( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && !defined('DOING_AJAX') )
        return;

    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        if( isset($cart_item['custom_data']['new_price']) )
            $cart_item['data']->set_price( (float) $cart_item['custom_data']['new_price'] );
    }
}

// Display cart item custom price details
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_item_price', 'display_cart_items_custom_price_details', 20, 3 );
function display_cart_items_custom_price_details( $product_price, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ){
    if( isset($cart_item['custom_data']['extra_charge']) ) {
        $product = $cart_item['data'];
        $product_price  = wc_price( wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array( 'price' => $product->get_regular_price() ) ) );
        $product_price .= '<br>' . wc_price( $cart_item['custom_data']['extra_charge'] ).'&nbsp;';
        $product_price .= __("Extra Charge", "woocommerce" );
    }
    return $product_price;
}
```

Code goes in `function.php` file
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your idea but I need to add the new line first between subtotal and total. I already now how to change the total price.

Comment: Hey! can you try the above code. Let me know if it's working I updated the code as per your requirement @Johnny97

Comment: Why adding an <input type="text" name="custom_price" value="" placeholder="e.g. 10" title="Custom Text" class="custom_price text_custom text"> ? This makes no sense for me because I now the name for the row and calculate the price in the backend in my functions.php

Comment: Cart Totals_____________

Cart Subtotal       $20
MyCustomField       $2.90

Order Total         $22.90
This the format you asked you have clearly mentioned custom field

Comment: Yes but why as a HTML input field? Makes absolutely no sense for me. The format there is like <tr><label>Custom field</label</tr>

Comment: To add extra price before total price you have to add the field for extra price field so for that field I have added custom field to enter an extra price

Comment: But I don't want the extra field related to the product. I need it in the cart totals. Take a look at the top, I've added a picture for you

Comment: I think you updated now? I will try for that Thanks @Johnny97